# server fail while running as windows service

Tags: sql, jboss, nssm

I have a jboss EAP7.1 server  that connect to windows sql server management studio 18 with windows authentification and start correctly . 
But when i've added the jboss server as a windows service with nssm https://nssm.cc/ so that the server  restart automatically when the vm/computer restart . it fail when the computer restart .

```
2020-04-30 16:22:18,454 WARN  [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (JCA PoolFiller) IJ000610: Unable to fill pool: java:/poc_DataSource: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ031084: Unable to create connection
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnectionFactory.getXAManagedConnection(XAManagedConnectionFactory.java:509)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(XAManagedConnectionFactory.java:416)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.java:1327)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.fillTo(SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.java:1139)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.PoolFiller.run(PoolFiller.java:97)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot open database "poc" requested by the login. The login failed. ClientConnectionId:8598e423-438a-4669-ba1d-7bde7c8f7c1b
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:262)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:258)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:104)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$1LogonProcessor.complete(SQLServerConnection.java:4752)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:5037)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:3668)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$000(SQLServerConnection.java:94)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:3627)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7194)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2935)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:2456)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:2103)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1950)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1162)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource.getConnectionInternal(SQLServerDataSource.java:1067)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPooledConnection.createNewConnection(SQLServerPooledConnection.java:81)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPooledConnection.<init>(SQLServerPooledConnection.java:56)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerXAConnection.<init>(SQLServerXAConnection.java:36)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerXADataSource.getXAConnection(SQLServerXADataSource.java:60)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerXADataSource.getXAConnection(SQLServerXADataSource.java:92)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnectionFactory.getXAManagedConnection(XAManagedConnectionFactory.java:494)
    ... 5 more

2020-04-30 16:22:18,484 WARN  [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (JCA PoolFiller) IJ000610: Unable to fill pool: java:/poc-editor_securityStore: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ031084: Unable to create connection
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnectionFactory.getXAManagedConnection(XAManagedConnectionFactory.java:509)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(XAManagedConnectionFactory.java:416)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.java:1327)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.fillTo(SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.java:1139)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.PoolFiller.run(PoolFiller.java:97)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot open database "poc" requested by the login. The login failed. ClientConnectionId:0ad5be24-214c-4936-a208-86a5a0170969
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:262)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:258)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:104)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$1LogonProcessor.complete(SQLServerConnection.java:4752)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:5037)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:3668)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$000(SQLServerConnection.java:94)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:3627)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7194)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2935)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:2456)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:2103)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1950)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1162)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource.getConnectionInternal(SQLServerDataSource.java:1067)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPooledConnection.createNewConnection(SQLServerPooledConnection.java:81)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPooledConnection.<init>(SQLServerPooledConnection.java:56)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerXAConnection.<init>(SQLServerXAConnection.java:36)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerXADataSource.getXAConnection(SQLServerXADataSource.java:60)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerXADataSource.getXAConnection(SQLServerXADataSource.java:92)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnectionFactory.getXAManagedConnection(XAManagedConnectionFactory.java:494)
```

Comment: Given the stack trace it looks more like a Microsoft SQL server and not MySQL. Is it hosted on the same computer?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins you are right it's microsoft sql server . and yes it's hosted on the same computer

Comment: My guess would be that JBoss EAP is started before the SQL server is started.

Comment: i've added a delay time so that the server start after 20s when the computer restart but i always have the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have changed the authentification in the standalone.xml from wivdows authentification to a user/passwd authentification and it's solved